# How can I get the current directory in an MSBuild script?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

In my MSBuild script I need to pass the full directory as a parameter. How can I get it?

Example: I am running the script from *C:\dev*, and I want a relative path, *temp*, so I am after *C:\dev\temp*.

Note: I don't know from which folder the script will be run.

Comment: Will your temp folder always be a sub folder of the location from which this script is to be run?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Igor is pretty close. `MSBuildProjectDirectory` is the property that will give you the full path to the project file which was invoked on the command line. So if you have the following scripts:

- C:\temp\MyProj.proj
- C:\shared\shared.targets

And `MyProj.proj` imports `shared.targets` and this is the one passed to msbuild.exe then the value for `MSBuildProjectDirectory` will always be **C:\temp** even if you are referencing that inside of shared.targets. If your shared.targets requires path knowledge then those should be declared in known properties. For example C# project files define the value for `OutputPath` and the shared file `Microsoft.Common.targets` uses that property.

**Edit: MSBuild 4**

If you are using MSBuild 4, you can also use these properties for this type of value.

- MSBuildThisFile
- MSBuildThisFileDirectory
- MSBuildThisFileDirectoryNoRoot
- MSBuildThisFileExtension
- MSBuildThisFileFullPath
- MSBuildThisFileName

See http://sedodream.com/2010/03/11/MSBuild40ReservedProperties.aspx.

Comment: +1 note that those new MSBuild 4 reserved properties are not listed in the list of macros in Visual Studio 2010 edit dialog even though they are supported

Answer (score 61):

Here are three targets that are helpful.

*WhereAmI* is the one I use when trying to figure out my current directory of course.

The others are informative as well (some are beyond the scope of the question).

```
<Target Name="WhereAmI">
    <Message Text=" Here I Am  " />
    <Exec Command="dir ." />
    <Message Text=" " />
</Target>



<Target Name="ShowReservedProperties" AfterTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Text=" MSBuildProjectDirectory  = $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text=" MSBuildProjectFile  = $(MSBuildProjectFile)" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text=" MSBuildProjectExtension  = $(MSBuildProjectExtension)" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text=" MSBuildProjectFullPath  = $(MSBuildProjectFullPath)" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text=" MSBuildProjectName  = $(MSBuildProjectName)" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text=" MSBuildBinPath  = $(MSBuildBinPath)" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text=" MSBuildProjectDefaultTargets  = $(MSBuildProjectDefaultTargets)" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text=" MSBuildExtensionsPath  = $(MSBuildExtensionsPath)" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text=" MSBuildStartupDirectory  = $(MSBuildStartupDirectory)" Importance="high"/>
</Target>


  <Target Name="ShowOtherProperties">
    <Message Text="  " />
    <Message Text="  " />
    <Message Text=" Environment (SET) Variables*       " />
    <Message Text=" ---------------------------        " />
    <Message Text=" COMPUTERNAME = *$(COMPUTERNAME)*   " />
    <Message Text=" USERDNSDOMAIN = *$(USERDNSDOMAIN)* " />
    <Message Text=" USERDOMAIN = *$(USERDOMAIN)*       " />
    <Message Text=" USERNAME = *$(USERNAME)*           " />
</Target>
```

If you're using an "external MSBuild file" and need to pass a filename or path to it (because external MSBuild files do not like relative files if they are not in the same directory as the calling .msbuild file)....here is a convenient (3.5 and up I believe) Task.

```
    <ConvertToAbsolutePath Paths="..\"> <!-- Some relative path here -->
      <Output TaskParameter="AbsolutePaths" PropertyName="MyAbsolutionPathProperty"/>
    </ConvertToAbsolutePath>
    <Message Text="'MyAbsolutionPathProperty' = '$(MyAbsolutionPathProperty)'" />
```

Comment: Why use `dir .` instead of `cd`?

Comment: dir '.' reports the directory.  cd is change_directory and will move me out of the folder.  I guess you could do "cd ." but I don't see what that gives you over "dir '.'"....

Comment: `dir .` prints out so much more than the working directory. `dir '.'` prints out an error message in addition to the CWD because no such file exists. [`CD`](http://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) with no arguments displays the current path without altering it. I am assuming we’re talking about cmd here, not what would happen if you ran your script through `xbuild` ;-).

Comment: dir '.' doesn't report an error for me.  It lists the directory and files/folders.  I don't know about xbuild.

Comment: http://imgur.com/fTudXkB , just sayin’ :-p. Works without the quotes but displays the directory listing instead of just your current directory (which is exactly and only what `CD` (with no arguments) prints out). Sorry, I’m nitpicking. But, for example, in `AppData\Local\Temp`, the output of `dir .` is quite unhelpful if you just want to know where you are because there are so many files in there…

Comment: 'dir .' printed my root (c:\). Strange.  'cd' printed out dir of exec'ing batch file.

Answer (score 13):

MSBuild has reserved property called `MSBuildProjectDirectory`, which is to the absolute path of the directory where you project or script file is located, C:\Dev in your case. Therefore `"$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\temp"` is exactly what you're looking for.