# MsBuild: Get current directory of targets

Tags: msbuild, path, directory, msbuild-task, targets

I have a msbuild target and it has a Import tag like this:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Company\Company.LifeCycle.targets" />
```

In contents of Company.LifeCycle.targets file, how can I get programatically the current directory (in this case is: **C:\Program Files\MsBuild\Company**) ??

I use VS 2008, .NET 3.5

Edit: I have seen the reference, [How can I get current directory in msbuild script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111256/how-can-i-get-current-directory-in-msbuild-script), but not valid for me: $(MSBuildProjectDirectory give me this value, C:\Work\Company\Projects\Test001\ProyectSW3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the current directory in an MSBuild script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111256/how-can-i-get-the-current-directory-in-an-msbuild-script)

Answer (score 11):

With MSBuild 4 you can use the new property 'MSBuildThisFileDirectory' see my blog http://sedodream.com/2010/03/11/MSBuild40ReservedProperties.aspx. If you are not using MSBuild 4, you cannot do this easily.

Comment: I use msbuild 3.5; source code not available for get new property 'MSBuildThisFileDirectory' like MsBuild Community Tasks or another extensions in codeplex ??

Comment: No this is an update to MSBuild itself. Instead of getting the path it needs to be passed in via a property.

Comment: @SayedIbrahimHashimi, your blog is not exactly clear on how to run the sample project there in order to see the reserved properties.

Comment: @TolaOdejayi the post has "msbuild ReservedProps02.proj /m /nologo" in the second code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Your question has already been answered in another post here: [MsBuild: Get current directory of targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111256/how-can-i-get-current-directory-in-msbuild-script). I hope the answers there satisfy you.

You can pretty much use `MSBuildProjectDirectory` which will give you the path to your current project file and you can build upon that.