# How do I keep Build parameters alive in TFS Build (TFS server 2017 and build agent 2013)

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, xamlbuild

I'm trying to figure out why my builds are failing, so in a .proj that the build calls I added:

```
<Message Text="System Drive: $(SystemDrive)"/>
<Message Text="BuildAgtentId: $(BuildAgentId)" />
<Message Text="BuildDefinitionPath: $(BuildDefinitionPath)" />
<Message Text="SourceDir: $(SourceDir)" />
<Message Text="SrcDir: $(SrcDir)" />
<Message Text="BuildDefinitionPath: $(BuildDefinitionPath)." />
<Message Text="BuildDefinitionId: $(BuildDefinitionId)." />
<Message Text="TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY: $(TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY)" />
```

Now in doing this I assumed that $(SourceDir) would resolve to C:\Builds\$(BuildDefinitionId) since that's what I have in my Working Directory setting for my agent. I also set a variable in the MSBuild Parameters:

```
/p:SrcDir=$(SourceDir)
```

But when the .proj runs here's my output:

```
System Drive: C:
BuildAgtentId: 
BuildDefinitionPath: 
SourceDir: 
SrcDir: $(SourceDir)
BuildDefinitionPath: .
BuildDefinitionId: .
TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY: .
```

So it seems as only $(SystemDrive) persists during the build. And my parameter set in the MSBuild args doesn't even seem to be set correctly (SrcDir). How can I access these variables during the build so I know where my files will be? I need to call some other programs (i.e. attrib) and pass in the location of my files and nothing seems to persist.

Based on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh850448%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Use%20environment%20variable%20data%20in%20MSBuild) article I thought for sure that TF_BUILDDIRECTORY would work but it doesn't.

I then tried using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399152(v=vs.100).aspx) article that says that this should work:

```
<GetBuildProperties TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TFSTeamFoundationServerUrl)" BuildUri="$(BuildUri)">
  <Output TaskParameter="BuildDirectory" PropertyName ="TFSBuildDirectory" />
  <Output TaskParameter="TeamProject" PropertyName="TFSTeamProject" />
</GetBuildProperties>

<Message Text="BuildLocation: $(TFSBuildDirectory)." />
<Message Text="TeamProject: $(TFSTeamProject)."/>
```

And while TeamProject works, BuildDirectory does not. So I get this:

```
BuildLocation: .
TeamProject: MDRVIDEOTOUCH.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [XAML build environment variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh850448%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).

Some of those values aren't available, but you can get some of them:

- **TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY** The build agent working directory. For example: C:\Build\BuildBot3\CoolApp\CIBuild.
- **TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER** The build number of the build. For example: CIBuild_20130613.6.
- **TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY** The sources sub-directory of the build agent working directory. This directory contains your source code. For example: C:\Build\BuildBot3\CoolApp\CIBuild\src.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but as I just updated the question above I tried TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY and that appears to be blank too (unless I'm referencing it wrong. I'm using $(TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY) - right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the value to MSBuild task through MSBuild arguments.

1. Define properties in PropertyGroup section of your project file, for example `<PropertyGroup><SourceDir></SourceDir><BuildDefinitionName></BuildDefinitionName></PropertyGroup>`
2. Specify MSBuild arguments: `/p:SourceDir="$(TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY)" /p: BuildDefinitionName="$(TF_BUILD_BUILDDEFINITIONNAME)"`

On the other hand, there are some variables in MSBuild, you can check this thread: [How can I get current directory in msbuild script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111256/how-can-i-get-current-directory-in-msbuild-script)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work. I set /p:SourceDir="$(TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY)" in the build definition  and then in the .proj file when I <meesage> the values I get: InitVariables:
  SourceDir: $(TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY). So the TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY isn't being translated - it's being taken as a literal.

Comment: @Ben_G You need to use SourceDir in MSBuild directly, for example: `<Message Importance="high" Text="InitVariables : $(SourceDir)"/>`. (The $(TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY) is used in TFS build activity)

Comment: @Ben_G What's the result after trying it?